# Matlab connection string to a local Postgres Db

Tags: postgresql, matlab

I have created a local Postgres Db on my computer, from where I am also running Matlab R2021b.
I am trying to set up a connection string to connect to my Db, without success.
Following is what I've tried (dbName = "myDbName", user = "myUser", passw = "myPassw")

```
Settings:
datasource = "PostgreSQLDataSource";
dbname = "myDbName"; % = datasource
username = "postgres";
password = "admin";
server = "127.0.0.1"; % localhost; %'server' = 'hostname'
port = 5432;
vendor = "PostgreSQL";
drivertype = "native";
%drivertype = "jdbc";
driver = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC\postgresql-42.5.1.jar"; % = "org.postgresql.Driver";
url = ['jdbc:postgresql://' server ':' num2str(port) '/' dbname];
%opts = databaseConnectionOptions(drivertype, vendor);    
%status = testConnection(opts,"","")

Connection:
%conn = postgresql(dbname, username, password)
%conn = postgresql(datasource, username, password)
%conn = database(datasource, username, password)
%conn = database(dbname, username, password)
%conn = database(dbname, username, password, hostname, port)
%conn = database(dbname, username, password, driver, url)
```

Any hints here?
Thanks in adavance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dbname = 'myDbName'; % = datasource
username = "postgres";
password = 'admin';
server = 'localhost'; % 127.0.0.1'; % 'server' = 'hostname'
port = '5432';
driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver';
url = ['jdbc:postgresql://' server ':' port '/' dbname];
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC\postgresql-42.5.1.jar');

try
    conn = database(dbname, username, password, driver, url);
    conn.AutoCommit = "off";
    %conn.LoginTimeout = 0;
    %conn.MaxDatabaseConnections = 100;

    if isopen(conn)
        disp('Database connection successful');
        %... put your queries here
        close(conn); % close the database connection

    else
        disp('Database connection failed');
    end
catch ME
    disp(['Error while processing data from file '  ': ' ME.message]);
end
```